# why asp.net dynamic charts are rendered only after the second page_load?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-charts

I am using web forms to develop a web application.
From the very beginning, I have always been surprised by the page_load event being fired twice, and finally today I found out that all gridviews and texts are rendered after first page_load, and it takes another page_load to render all the dynamic asp.net charts..

why is it so, is there an attribute on the chart web server control that I can use to bypass this?

Comment: The page_load event should not be firing twice.  The charts should render immediately.  There must be something wrong in your code.  Why don't you post a small sample that illustrates the problem?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Chart1Bind();
        }
    }
 protected void Chart1Bind()
    {
  //fetching values for the charts
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(x1, y1);
     //formatting stuff comes here
    }

Comment: Take the Chart1Bind function OUT of the IsPostBack clause.

Comment: I do not think so, because I tested without IsPostBack, it is the same story..

Comment: And I need IsPostBack since I am using AJAX UpdatePanel

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you "AutoEventWireup" set to true.  If this is a control, check the parent control/page also.  Even if the control itself is set to false, but the parent is set to true, it seems to fire anyway.
Also check where you assign listener to `Page_Load` event:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
```

Should be in `InitializeComponent` method